# Haskell: How to define strict tuples

Tags: haskell, lazy-evaluation

Lets say I have the following:

```
f (a, b) = if a == 0 then (0, 0) else (a * b, a / b)

x1 = make_strict (0, undefined)
x2 = (0, undefined)

g f :: (b -> b) -> a -> a
```

How do define `make_strict` and `g`:

```
g f x = ... f x ...
make_strict x = ...
```

So that:

```
g f x1 == undef
g f x2 == (0, 0)
```

Basically I want to make a strict version of a pair that I can then pass to a function which takes a pair, possibly through a wrapper `g` if necessary. The particular implementation of `f` here is just an example, the solution shouldn't rely on it. The point is I can't change `f`, I can only change `g`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about

```
makeStrict (a, b) = seq a (seq b (a, b))
```

Comment: Thanks, though your answer makes me realize that perhaps this question isn't a good one and misses the point of what I'm trying to do.